# Работа с переменными (объектами) в шаблонах

Tags: php, ооп, шаблонизаторы

Здравствуйте. Никак не дорасту до ООП, начинаю практически с азов.
Суть такова, как удобнее или как правильнее пользоваться переменными в концепции ООП, в том числе в HTML шаблонах? Знаю, что можно подглядеть фреймворках, но бывает все запутанно из-за их множества классов, наследований...
Примеры: 
Простейшая реализация шаблона, через include. Данные передаются из класса

```
<?php
// Например, class User extends COntroller 
$data = ['var' => 'Exapmle'];
$this->view->showView('home', $data);
// В конструкторе Controller
$this->view = new View();
```

Во вьюшке все работает. Теперь есть статический метод Error::isError().
Вот тут вопрос: Как можно его "впихнуть" View, чтобы автоматом принимать его?
Передачей в шаблон и прописав namespace в HTML шаблоне home работаeт. Но каждый раз там прописывать не хотелось бы.
Похожая ситуация с классом User. Как в шаблоне проверить, что пользователь залогинился?

```
// HTML код
    <?php if ((класс User->)isLogged()): ?>
        <a href="/profile/">Profile</a>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php if (Error::isError()): ?>Возникла ошибка.<?php endif; ?>
```

Вообщем как правильно инкапсуляцию провернуть?

**UPD:** Пока использую подобное:

```
// В контроллере
$data = ['error' => Error::show(), 'user' => $this->user->getUserData()];
$this->view->showView('user/sing_up', $data);
// Во вью
<?php if (!empty($error)): ?>
    <p style="color: #f00000;"><?php echo $error; ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($user): ?>
    <a href="/profile/">Profile</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Но, если кто-то посоветует еще решения будет неплохо.

Хелперы еще не "прошел", поэтому в дальнейшем может сделаю

Comment: Из простого - положите в `$data` экземпляр класса User, и в представлении будет $user->isLogged(). Проверка ошибок в шаблонах, думаю не лучший вариант. Можно проверить на ошибки и внутри контроллера, и выдать представление с ошибкой. Тут вопрос больше архитектуры. Фреймворки стоит поковырять, ну или попробовать для начала, ознакомиться с подходами.

Comment: Я уже написал в вопросе, что проще передать, но мне хотелось бы наследовать. Если проверять в контроллере, надо использовать html, ведь так? Опять неверное применение. Во фреймворках сложно понять что куда, ибо там учтены многие вещи. Они то сводят с толку как работает простейшее..

Comment: Что от чего наследовать вы собираетесь? Вы имеете ввиду просто в представлениях подключать? Ну подключайте никто не мешает, это вопрос выбора, и как с этим дальше жить. Зачем в контроллере использовать html для каких либо проверок? Не совсем понимаю, я конечно не знаю что у вас там происходит в isError, но для исключений стоит использовать глобальный компонент который будет ловить исключения и перенаправлять на страницу с ошибкой. Фреймворки не такие страшные как вы думаете, стоит только попробовать разобраться.

Comment: Вся соль в написании своего)

Comment: error по сути массив с пунктами ошибок, потом implode() и вывод во View. Iserror - есть ли массив ошибок, тру фолс. С класом юзер я чуть понял, что не нужно весь класс пихать. Хотя если будут условия для каждой группы пользователей свой html, то придется переменную передать во View. А хотел я, чтобы объект User или еще какой был во View. Например, для выбора, если админ - вывести админ панель, если юзер - в профиль, иначе - Войти

Comment: MVC стоит перечитать. "Например для выбора" - это опять же стоит вынести в контроллер и не выводить вьюхи а перенаправлять по адресам/контроллерам разным. В контроллере перед обработкой какого либо кода, вынести проверку на разрешение находиться по данному адресу. Проверку ошибок, ну по разному можно делать конечно, под каждой реализацией по разному. В представлении можно проверять ошибки которые относятся к конкретной вьюхе, например если ошибка от модели, то должно быть User::isError() нежели глобальный компонент. Если глобальные ошибки то отдельно проверять, а не писать в каждой вьюхе.

Comment: Я думаю нас могут забанить, развели тему.. Вообщем ответа пока не будет. Насчет проверок, доступ ограничен, понятное дело. Но на главной странице я же не буду из за строчки дублировать шаблоны. Ошибки можно затереть после вывода и они как бы не глобальны. И на первое время занести так     $data = ["errors"=>Error::showError()];

Answer (score 1):

Если вы не хотите передавать параметры во вью, но иметь возможность их запросить из вью. Я бы сделал некое подобие view helpers. Т.е. вы из вью вызываете некий объект который содержит необходимые переменные. И из например из любого места в вашем коде наполняете этот объект.

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите, php изначально развивался как шаблонизатор. все эти вкрапления кода в html в духе `<?= $variable ?>` (вместо `<?php echo ... ?>`) и т.д. - наследие тех времен.

Его и сейчас можно использовать таким образом, но в больших/средних проектах - это редкость.  Как правило, используются шаблонизаторы без внедрения php-кода.

Сравните Symfony 1 / 2:  в Symfony 1  можно было использовать шаблоны в виде нативных php-файлов, в Symfony 2 - обычно используют twig.

Использование шаблонизаторов вроде twig преследует две цели:

- полностью удалить логику приложения из представления (начинающий программист не сможет вставить вызов бд в шаблон)
- разделить верстальщиков и программистов (дешевле и быстрее)

Вопрос у вас, таким образом, не один, а целых три, поэтому дам три ответа:

1) Вам не следует путать парадигму построения приложений MVC (model-view-controller) и парадигму программирования ООП.

2) Вы вполне можете использовать парадигму MVC на функциональном или процедурном языке, без использования ООП.

3) Шаблон не должен проверять, залогинился ли пользователь, проверять это должен контроллер и либо менять шаблон для view, либо менять переменные в текущем view

Answer (score 1):

В PHP как и любом другом языке крайне опасно мешать **логику и отображение** . Для этого существует **MVC** - суть его проста, разделяй и властвуй. Вся логика обрабатывается в контроллерах, которые передают в виды некоторые параметры, которые могут быть и объектами. Но логика и расчёты этих параметров инкапсулированны. Поэтому - то как вы всё сделали: всё правильно.

Передаваемые объекты могут быть ActiveRecord-ами полученными из моделей(или их можно назвать слой ORM) - и нету ничего страшного в их передаче, особенно если контроллер автоматически лочит их на запись. Без лока - ActiveRecord можно очень легко перезаписать в базу ( но даже без лока на 800 видах никто у нас так не делал ).

Далее - вид: есть суть шаблон. PHP является сам по себе прекрасным шаблонизатором. И использование именно PHP (а не твиг) для шаблонов открывает прекрасные возможности шаблонизации:

```
<? if ($this->error){ ?>
    <p style="color: #f00000;"><?=$error->toString()?></p>
<? } ?>
<? if ($this->user){ ?>
    <a href="<?=$user->getHref()?>"><?=$user->getTitle()?></a>
<? } ?>
```

А именно вызов методов из объектов переданных в вид - что делает построение видов очень гибким. Сумасшедшие верстальщики отнюдь не пытаются коннектиться к БД в коде вида - даже без денежной дубинки, ни подрядчики, ни собственные программисты - ну никто не хочет быть полным оленем в своей профессии.

Использование twig и прочих - это либо нечто навязанное фреймворком (например симфони), либо акт крайнего недоверия создателям видов (верстальщикам например). Так и знайте - если вы верстальщик, и у вас в компании меняют вёрстку PHP->twig - это либо самодуры-менеджеры, либо отношение к верстальщикам: как к обезьянам. Последний абзац - ИМХО.

Comment: Пишу для себя одного, поэтому, если продолжу кодить, то там уже посмотрю, что  изменить. Сейчас важнее понимать суть, и разрабатывать логику что и как хранить, куда писать И как использовать для отображения. Да объект могут и удалить, если написать нечто $user->delete() но пусть это решается копией объекта для View.

Comment: @ozornick - можно, поэтому я и писал "лочить их на запись" - то есть и на удаление в том числе. Но на практике никто не хочет лишиться ползарплаты - у нас 800 таких видов, ни разу в них так не говнокодили (5 лет). Хотя мы лок не делали раньше. На крайнях таблицу восстановят из дампа. Если уж взяли того, кто в программировании вообще ничего не соображает (чтобы съекономить) - проблемы начальства.